# On Cubic Non-Residues Modulo a Prime

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, computational-number-theory

What is a good test for identifying cubic non-residues/residues and higher power non-residues/residues modulo a prime $R$ in terms of computational complexity?

Given $M$ and $N$, is there a good way to find a prime $R$ such that $M$ is cubic non-residue modulo $R$ and $N$ is cubic residue modulo $R$?

Update after David Speyer's answer: Does the probability estimate hold good if $R$ is restricted to be between $M$ and $N$ and $M < 2N$ or $N < 2M$?

Comment: What does $N$ have to do with it?

Comment: Off topic. BTW $a_i = M^{-1}$ is a counterexample to (1).

Comment: Do not make your question into a moving target. You already got two correct answers to two versions of your question. Accept one of them, try to learn what they mean and think about your problem some more. Then ask in a new question what you really want to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that $M$, $N$, $M N$ and $M N^2$ are noncubes, for a random prime $p$, the probability that $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$ and $M$ is a cube mod $p$ and $N$ is not a cube  is $1/9$. Trying some random primes and checking as Igor Rivin describes is probably faster than trying to be clever.

Proof of the probability claim: The hypotheses imply that the splitting field of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{M}, \sqrt[3]{N})$ has Galois group $\mathbb{Z}/2 \ltimes (\mathbb{Z}/3)^2$. Here, writing $\zeta$ for a primitive cube root of unity, this group acts by
$$\pm 1 \ltimes (a,b) \ : \ (\zeta, \sqrt[3]{M}, \sqrt[3]{N}) \mapsto (\zeta^{\pm 1}, \zeta^a \sqrt[3]{M}, \zeta^b \sqrt[3]{N}).$$

Let $\epsilon_p \ltimes (a_p,b_p)$ be the (conjugacy class of) the frobenius at $p$. Then $p \equiv 1 \bmod 3$  if and only if $\epsilon_p=1$; the numbers $M$ and $N$ are a cubic residue and non-residue respectively if and only if $a_p=0$ and $b_p \neq 0$. By the Cebatarov density theorem, we see that the proportion of primes which obey these properties is $2/18 = 1/9$.

Comment: Thankyou. Does the same probability hold if the prime has to be between $M$ and $N$ if $N < 2M$ or $M < 2N$?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the density theorem. Could you provide the details for $2/18$ step?

Comment: To your first question, I don't know. To the second question: Cebatarov density states that, for $C$ a conjugacy closed subset of a Galois group $G$, the probability that $Frob(p)$ will be in $C$ is $|C|/|G|$. In this case, the Galois group has $18$ elements and $2$ of them work. For the Cebatarov density theorem, see an "advanced" textbook in algebraic number theory, such as Janusz (Algebraic Number Fields) or Neukirch (Algebraic Number Theory).

Comment: Oh I see. Total #of $\epsilon_{p}$ is $2$ (which counts $\pm $), total number of $a_{p},b_{p}$ each is $3$ (which counts $0,1,2$). So total possibilities is $18$. Of which we want $\epsilon_{p}=1$, $a_{p}=0$ and $b_{p}\in \{1,2\}$. This counts to $2/18$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I am guessing the answer is same for the first question as well as $M,N \rightarrow \infty$ since the number of primes to choose from in the middle increases linearly in $M$ and $N$. What is your opinion?

Comment: Sorry, my opinion is that I don't know. If you held $M$ and $N$ fixed and looked at primes between $T$ and $2T$, you'd be right, but I don't know enough about the error bounds in Cebatarov to know what happens when you link the endpoints of your interval to the cubic extension. But there are plenty of experts here!

Comment: Ok. Thankyou very much.

Answer (score 4):

I am a bit confused by the connection between the first question and the numbered questions. Presumably if $R\equiv 2 \mod 3,$ then everything is a cubic residue, while if $R\equiv 1 \mod 3,$ then $x$ is a residue iff $x^{(R-1)/3} \equiv 1 \mod R.$ This test is quite efficient. I assume (but haven't bothered to check) that this test will answer the numbered questions.

Comment: Removed the trivial part

Comment: what about for higher residues?